# ASPX-Handler calls full website lifecycle again

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, ashx, page-lifecycle

My ASPX website has CSS files and JS files linked as ASHX files. So for example I got `<script type="application/javascript" src="/JavaScript.ashx"></script>` in my markup.
When I debug the website in Chrome (newest version without add-ons) it calls the entire life cycle again.

For test purposes I cleared the ProcessRequest method of my handlers and I accessed it directly. (`http://localhost:1234/JavaScript.aspx`). 
After my handler finished the ProcessRequest method it jumps into the Default() constructor of Default.aspx (after that it continues to run through the whole life cycle obviously). I think after the request Chrome did access (`http://localhost:1234/`) in the background for unknown reason and called the life cycle of my Default.aspx seperately with `IsPostBack = false` and `IsCallback = false`.

The weird thing is in Internet Explorer 11 I do not face this problem.

How can this be?
Is this a problem of Chrome only? 
Will it even appear when using a live version? 
Is there any work around?

Comment: Have you checked `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` for each request? Note that your post have no information to suggest what could be happening - no sample code that shows the issue, no urls that are requested... For all we know the code in `ProcessRequest` checks for Chrome user agent and does 302 redirect to home.

Comment: The problem is I cannot reproduce this with a new project, so it has to be something with my code. The RawUrl is `/JavaScript.ashx` for my handler and `/` after it calls my Default.aspx which I don't want. I got a lot of code in my master page and content pages, but I cannot imagine this has something to do with it, since I call the ASHX file directly. So i now decided to rename the ASPX and MASTER files and see what happens: Nothing, it will proceed through the ProcessRequest and done, no more call to any methods. Maybe this is a configuration problem.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem, I just wonder why Chrome assumed a 404 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what it was caused by: My web.config contained

```
    <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="/" />
    </customErrors>
```

and

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" path="/" responseMode="Redirect" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

I know that's the wrong way to handle 404 responses, but I was not on the way to leave it. I just wonder why Chrome gets a 404 response, even when my handler returns content?
Because this is the only reason how it could forward to "/" and repeat my life cycle.